# Magento2:-Add product Grid in the product admin side

Tags: magento2, product, product-grid

**I searched for that, but I could not find any resource. How to add product grid in to "Add product" in admin side like related product?**

[image]

Comment: -> https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-product-edit-pages-in-magento-2.html
-> https://webkul.com/blog/add-product-tab-specific-product-type-custom-module-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

> vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="salable_quantity" sortOrder="55">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Product Salable Quantity</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>false</opened>
            <visible>0</visible>
        </settings>
        <container name="salable_quantity_container" template="Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi/product/form/salable-quantity" sortOrder="10">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                    <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="salable_quantity" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.salable_quantity</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```